# Fetching data from Postgresq Database using sqlalchemy.select() in python

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am using python and SQLalchemy to fetch data from a table.

```
import sqlalchemy as db
import pandas as pd

DATABASE_URI = 'postgres+psycopg2://postgres:postgresql@localhost:5432/postgres'
engine = db.create_engine(DATABASE_URI)
connection = engine.connect()
project_table = db.Table('project', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
```

here i want to fetch records based on a list of ids which i have.

```
 l=[557997, 558088, 623106, 558020, 623108, 557836, 557733, 622792, 623511, 623185] 
 query1 = db.select([project_table ]).where(project_table .columns.project_id.in_(l))
 #sql query= "select * from project where project_id in l"
 Result = connection.execute(query1)
 Rset = Result.fetchall()
 df = pd.DataFrame(Rset)
 print(df.head())
```

Here when i print df.head() I am getting an empty dataframe. I am not able to pass a list to the above query. Is there a way to send a list to in to above query.

The result should contain the rows in the table which are equal to project_id's given.
i.e.

```
project_id  project_name  project_date project_developer
557997       Test1        24-05-2011    Ajay
558088       Test2        24-06-2003    Alex
```

These rows will be inserted into dataset.
The Query is

```
"select * from project where project_id in (557997, 558088, 623106, 558020, 623108, 557836, 557733, 622792, 623511, 623185)"
```

here as i cant give static values I will insert the values to a list and pass this list to query as a parameter.
This is where i am having a problem. I cant pass a list as a parameter to db.select().How can i pass a list to db.select()

Comment: Please produce a [mcve], including a small sample of the data (in the database).

Comment: The query is a bit odd, since the proper syntax for `IN` would be `in (...)`, not `in [...]`, but I suppose that's a typo. Given the example in the question, you should be getting rows back. Have you checked what `Rset` looks like? Are you sure you're connecting to the correct DB?

Comment: yes, I have connected to correct db. I am not getting anything back when I use list as parameter.How can i pass a list to db.select(). The data which i am fetching is more than 50GB. If not db.select()  can you tell me which libraries i can use to fetch data quickly.

Comment: Your `query1` should work as is, the list is bound as parameters by SQLAlchemy Core.

Comment: Even if I directly try to print the some values in Rset by saying print(Rset[0:100]), It gives an empty list.

Comment: Btw. is the `Result` vs. `ResultProxy` only a typo in the question? Or do you maybe have a previously consumed result bound to `ResultProxy`?

Comment: As a side note, if you want to produe pandas `DataFrame`s from your results, you could maybe use `pandas.read_sql_query()` directly and skip the manual steps.

Comment: pandas.read_sql_query()  is taking more time, so i am searching or alternatives

Comment: 50 Jigabytes? Great Scott!

Answer (score 2):

After many trails i have found out that because of large data the query is fetching and also less ram in my workstation, the query returned null(no results). so what I did was

```
 Result = connection.execute(query1)
            while True:
                rows = Result.fetchmany(10000)
                if not rows:
                    break
                for row in rows:
                    table_data.append(row)
                    pass
            df1 = pd.DataFrame(table_data)
            df1.columns = columns
```

After this the program was working fine.